# Can multiple applications use the same MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql

Am I right in thinking that you only need ONE installation of MySQL per computer....and different platforms could then use this?
For example, both PHP and RubyonRails could run on the same installation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. All clients access the mysql database over the network, thus there is no limitation on the clients (programming-)language. See the mysql downloads http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ for some client connectors from mysql itself (there are more).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

Mysql works with server (installation) and clients. Normally the server only accepts clients that run on the same machine. Meaning you can have many clients running from the same database server which holds multiple database.

It is also possible to allow mysql to accept requests from clients from other computers. Then you would only need 1 server for clients on many computers. Do note that you have to think about safety and firewalls when you allow mysql to accept remote connections.